# How to remove vocals from a song?

Tags: voice

I want to create a karaoke version from existing songs. What technique can be used to remove the vocals from the songs?

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is - none.

There have been many bits of software over the years claiming to be able to do it, but frankly, unless the vocal is clean, dead-centre & has no effects on it, you're not going to really get anywhere at all.

The purported method is to split the stereo track, then phase-invert one side; which sounds horrible & only vaguely works anyway.

This page has a list of software purported to be able to do it… http://mp3.about.com/od/essentialsoftware/tp/Top_Vocal_Removers.htm

I'd recommend trying any free ones, but don't pay for one unless it's got a trial period so you can test it first & decide for yourself.

Comment: What Tetsujin said & really try hard to find an instrumental of the song, I would even consider resorting to a midi version before trying to remove vocals.